# updating locale needs to override OnConfigurationChange which is not directing to layout-land xml which is again needed

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I have been using Locale for app language which on orientation change needs to be reconfigured.

But in my code I have to direct my activity to layout-land for which i need to destroy and recreate my activity to reset the Xmls.

Can anyone tell me how do i override `OnConfigurationChange(Configuraion config)` and still direct my layout to layout-land without destroying activity.

Is this Possible ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okkk this is what i did...I commented the android:config tab on my manifest file...and didnot override onConfigurationChange(Configuration config) which will recreate my activity on orientation change...I copy pasted my updateConfig(Locale locale) to my onCreate()..it is working perfectly fine..without changing state of my view

Thanks for help